ubuntu 24.04 kern.log shows nouveau errors webkitprocess hundereds of time
kern.log shows the following errors from the last boot.
2024-10-13T09:51:41.358728-07:00 ace kernel: nouveau 0000:05:00.0: gr: DATA_ERROR 0000009c [] ch 5 [007fb4b000 WebKitWebProces[31465]] subc 0 class 9097 mthd 0d78 data 00000004
2024-10-13T09:52:06.362122-07:00 ace kernel: message repeated 1445 times: [ nouveau 0000:05:00.0: gr: DATA_ERROR 0000009c [] ch 5 [007fb4b000 WebKitWebProces[31465]] subc 0 class 9097 mthd 0d78 data 00000004]
2024-10-13T09:52:44.941995-07:00 ace kernel: nouveau 0000:05:00.0: gr: DATA_ERROR 0000009c [] ch 5 [007fb4b000 WebKitWebProces[31693]] subc 0 class 9097 mthd 0d78 data 00000004
2024-10-13T09:53:40.874177-07:00 ace kernel: message repeated 1521 times: [ nouveau 0000:05:00.0: gr: DATA_ERROR 0000009c [] ch 5 [007fb4b000 WebKitWebProces[31693]] subc 0 class 9097 mthd 0d78 data 00000004]

2024-10-13T14:15:22.411010-07:00 ace kernel: nouveau 0000:05:00.0: gr: DATA_ERROR 0000009c [] ch 5 [007fb48000 WebKitWebProces[58041]] subc 0 class 9097 mthd 0d78 data 00000004
2024-10-13T14:15:27.505006-07:00 ace kernel: message repeated 693 times: [ nouveau 0000:05:00.0: gr: DATA_ERROR 0000009c [] ch 5 [007fb48000 WebKitWebProces[58041]] subc 0 class 9097 mthd 0d78 data 00000004]


2024-10-13T18:45:11.901679-07:00 ace kernel: nouveau 0000:05:00.0: gr: DATA_ERROR 0000009c [] ch 6 [007fa7a000 WebKitWebProces[80486]] subc 0 class 9097 mthd 0d78 data 00000004
2024-10-13T18:45:17.821586-07:00 ace kernel: message repeated 705 times: [ nouveau 0000:05:00.0: gr: DATA_ERROR 0000009c [] ch 6 [007fa7a000 WebKitWebProces[80486]] subc 0 class 9097 mthd 0d78 data 00000004]

Anyone have a idea what is causing these?
Nouveau is working okay except for not turning off the monitor when the time expires and the screen blanks.
Thanks Jim
